# Sub-space of infinite dimension proof

Tags: functional-analysis

$$V=\bigg\{ f\in{C}\big( \left[ -1,1 \right],\mathbb{R}\big)\quad :\quad f(-1)=0 \bigg\}\subset{C}\big( \left[ -1,1 \right],\mathbb{R}\big)$$

Prof this is a sub-space of infinite dimension, please help me out!

Deiota

Answer (score 1):

That it's a subspace, can be verified by the axioms:

If $f,g\in V$, i.e. $f(-1)=g(-1)=0$, then $f+g\in V$ and $\lambda f\in V$, as well (for $\lambda\in\Bbb R$).

And for its dimension, observe e.g. that the polynomials $(x+1)x^n$ are in $V$, and they are *linearly independent*.